# Wiki post turns non-wiki!

Tags: support, community-wiki

The answer to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46375/keyboard-settings-on-emulator-revert-on-restart) question which was automatically turned into a community-wiki post not long ago is now, once again a non-wiki post! I checked the 'activity' section of my user profile page. There is no account for this change there either!

This raises a curious question: On what basis is a community-wiki post turned (automatically or not) into a non-wiki post?

Comment: This would be a new change. I know there has been some discussion on auto-CW, but I haven't (yet) seen where they've made a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my doing. I saw your (deleted) meta question about why your answer was a CW. I didn't  think it deserved to be a CW answer, so I reverted it back to a normal answer. Any further edits should not make it CW again unless a mod reverses it.

Comment: Why didn't this reversal show in the post edits?

Comment: @AlEverett No idea, I just mod -> remove wiki. Doesn't seem to leave a mark on the answer's history that this was done. Might be a good suggestion for meta.SO.

Comment: There is actually a history entry for this action, @Al... But for some reason it's not visible to most users (not even to moderators). There are a handful of such history types, mostly falling into the category of "things we might need if a moderator is abusing their power but which aren't generally interesting" - I'm not so sure "removed wiki" falls into this bucket, but that's where it currently sits. FWIW, moderators are generally happy to remove CW status when there's only one author and no evidence of abuse.